# Testing equality of symbols using the Ruby C API

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am trying to find a way to test symbol equality in the Ruby C API. Consider the following C function:

```
static VALUE test_symbol_equality(VALUE self, VALUE symbol) {
  if (rb_intern("test") == symbol) {
    return Qtrue;
  } else {
    return Qfalse;
  }
}
```

From the Ruby point of view, this method does not behave as expected:

```
test_symbol_equality(:test)    # => false
```

Why is this the case? How do I need to change the code to achieve the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not comparing the same thing in your example.

`rb_intern` returns an `ID`, but you are comparing it to the `VALUE` directly. You first have to "unwrap" the `VALUE`, retrieving the `ID` it is associated with. Replacing your `if` statement by this should solve your problem:

```
if (rb_intern("test") == SYM2ID(symbol)) {
    ...
```